# Morse flow: cancelling handle pairs away from deformation retract

Tags: homotopy-theory, morse-theory, gradient-flows, retraction

Given a smooth manifold (not closed, maybe with boundary) $M$ in $R^n$, take a section with a hyperplane $H$ of some dimension $d$. Assume that $M$ has $M\cap H$ as deformation retract. For example, a cylinder.

Now we pick the function squared distance to $H$. If it is not a Morse function, deform it a bit so that you have a Morse function. Let $f$ be that function.

**Question:** Is it true that one can give *a* deformation retract of $M$ onto $M\cap H$ as the *flow of the vector field given by the gradient* $\nabla f$?

**My idea:** If $\nabla f$ does not vanish you are done. Assume that it vanishes. Since you have all the homotopy information in $f^{-1}(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, the handles that you attach at each critical level are not *that important*, so (what I expect is that) there is a pairing of critical points that cancel each other: there is a deformation of the Morse function through Morse functions that finishes cancelling pairs of critical points of indexes $(r,r+1)$. The end result is that you have a deformation retract given by the flow of $f$, or a modification of $f$.

I know that the cancellation is at least algebraic, but I wonder if it is geometric as well.

Comment: cool question, I don't know the answer. Are you assuming that $d< n-1$?... otherwise there can be alot of components that $H$ cuts $M$ into which is a bit confusing

Comment: @AndresMejia Thank you! In my case $M$ is a complex manifold in $\mathbb{C}^N$ and I take the intersection with the real part $\mathbb{R}^N$. So, to answer your question, in principle yes, $d<n-1$. By hypothesis $H$ cuts $M$ only once, should I state something more?